# CSS page Scroll issue

Tags: html, css

First of all, l would like to hide the normal Window Scrollbar.

These are the changes l want:

- The yellow section height should be auto (Can be more than the page's height)
- The scroll Bar must be on both the yellow, white and the green section
- When l scroll, l want the yellow, white and green section to move together
- When l resize the page (vertical or horizontal) all the above should still work

**current HTML**

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div class="topbar">
       RED SECTION
</div>

<div class="left side-menu">
        THE BLUE SECTION
</div>

<div class="content-page">
     YELLOW SECTION
<footer>
    THE GREEN SECTION
</footer>

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Current CSS:**

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.topbar {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

body.fixed-left .side-menu.left {
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -70px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 146px;
    position: fixed;
    width:240px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-page {
    margin-left: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Issues l am having now**

- When l change the height to 1000px, the green section gets hidden
- When the browser tab's height is reduced, some part of the page gets hidden
  and scrolling doesn't show it

Thanks [image]

Comment: First of all, you cannot alter the browser behavior from your code.  
in other words you cannot remove the scrollbar which is browser dependent.  
post some code for other issues.

Comment: @Elie Nassif Of course he can just add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent `<html>` this will hide the scrollbar

Comment: @ElieNassif l do not agree with you. It can be hidden with overflow:hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can get this using some tricks with position fixed for the green, blue and red sections, with positions top, left, right or bottom, and then overlay them with z-index.

After that you can place the yellow section fitting whole page with paddings fitting the overlapped areas (if blue section goes from left:0 and its width is 100px, then padding-left: 100px). Same for red and green. After that, create a container inside the yellow with height 100% width 100%, overflow-y:auto, it would fit the scroll area, and put the content inside this container.

Dont forget to disable initial scroll with `html, body {overflow:none}`. If you need more details, when i have access to my PC ill explain it better :)